# How to include a proper name in the from address of emails sent from nlog

Tags: nlog

I want emails sent by nlog to include the program name with the sent from address. All the examples I've seen simply have the email address in the *from* attribute. How can I add a proper name to that field?

```xml
<target xsi:type="Mail"
        name="mailserver1"
        subject="Layout"
        to="someguy@fake.com"
        from="john.doe@example.com"
        smtpServer="mx1.example.com" 
        smtpPort="Integer"
        layout="Layout" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched everywhere and finally just figured out how to do it myself. I later found instructions in [the documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target#user-content-email-address-format) which agree with my method. I hope this saves someone some time. The name should come first, then the email address should be surrounded with angle brackets (`<>`). Angle brackets aren't allowed in the XML config, so you must escape them.

```xml
<target xsi:type="Mail"
        name="mailserver1"
        subject="Layout"
        to="someguy@fake.com"
        from="John Doe &lt;john.doe@example.com&gt;"
        smtpServer="mx1.example.com" 
        smtpPort="Integer"
        layout="Layout" />
```

Comment: @Julian, s.o. won't let me until tomorrow